# How to write JOOQ query to get only one java record containing all results

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have the following java records :

```
record Info(Integer count){}
record Person(Integer id, String name) {}
record MyResult(Info info, List<Person> persons){}
```

I need to return a MyResult Object containing the total count of persons in Info and a partial list of these persons.

I have no idea if it is possible to do it directly with only one JOOQ query and how to do it.

Here is an attempt but obviously it will fetch a list so this is not the correct way.

```
DSL.getContext(conn)
  .select(
    DSL.row(DSL.count().over()).mapping(Info::new),
    DSL.multiset(
      DSL.select(
         PERSON.PERSON_ID,
         PERSON.NAME
      ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(PERSON::new)))
    )
  )
   .from(PERSON)
   .where(PERSON.NAME.startWith("A"))
   .orderBy(PERSON.NAME.asc())
   .offset(0)
   .limit(5) 
   .fetchOne(Records.mapping(MyResult::new));
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is [SQL's logical order of operations](https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/). Any means of counting results (both aggregate counts and window counts) happens *before* the `LIMIT` is applies. So, if you don't want `LIMIT` to have any effect on your count, you have to write the query in a way that it counts first. But if you don't get any results from your `WHERE` clause, then you don't get any rows when using window counts. When using aggregate counts, you'd get a row, but you can't apply `LIMIT` so easily anymore. (Without the `LIMIT`, you could simply use aggregate count and [`multisetAgg()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/) instead).

So, I can see 2 solutions, a slow but simple one, a faster but more complex one:

### Doing everything in the query, accessing the table twice:

If you want to move all the mapping logic into the query itself, I suspect you'd have to run 2 queries against the `PERSON` table, which probably isn't desirable for performance reasons:

```java
ctx.select(
      count().filterWhere(PERSON.NAME.startsWith("A")).convertFrom(Info::new),
      multiset(
        select(PERSON_ID, PERSON_NAME)
        .from(PERSON)
        .where(PERSON.NAME.startsWith("A"))
        .orderBy(PERSON.NAME.asc())
        .limit(5)
      ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(mapping(Person::new)))
    )
   .from(PERSON)
   .fetchOne(mapping(MyResult::new))
```

This works for your simple example, but as soon as you start joining things, you will have to duplicate a lot of query logic between the inner and outer query, and that's not really desirable.

### Using JDK `Collector` API

But you don't have to form the query in a hierarchical way like your target data structure. You can still do *some* mapping logic in the client as well, outside of jOOQ, e.g.:

```java
ctx.select(
      count().over().convertFrom(Info::new),
      row(PERSON_ID, PERSON_NAME).mapping(Person::new)
    )
    .from(PERSON)
    .where(PERSON.NAME.startsWith("A"))
    .orderBy(PERSON.NAME.asc())
    .limit(5)
    .collect(collectingAndThen(
        groupingBy(
            // There's a single possible value from count().over()
            r -> r.value1(),
            mapping(r -> r.value2(), toList())
        ),
        m -> {
            // Probably, just use var here...
            Iterator<Entry<Info, List<Person>>> it = m.entrySet().iterator();

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                Entry<Info, List<Person>> e = it.next();
                return new MyResult(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }
            else
                return new MyResult(new Info(0), Collections.emptyList());
        }
    )));
```

This is assuming the following static import:

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

Granted, it's not so pretty. You could maybe refactor this into a different format or write some more generic utility for this sort of result, but I hope you get the essence of it.

**Note:** this approach won't give you the correct count value if you paginate beyond the last page